# OpenLayers3 - is it possible to combine modify/draw/select operations?

Tags: openlayers-3

I've started using OpenLayers3 in my app, and so far, I have succeeded in creating working versions of:

1. a combined draw/modify page (based on the relevant example, `draw-and-modify-features.js`)
2. a combined select/modify page (based on the relevant example, `modify-features.js`)

In the case of (1), the `ol.interaction.Modify` instance specifies that it will work on the features inside an `ol.FeatureOverlay` instance:

```
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: featureOverlay.getFeatures()
...
```

...and it is that `ol.FeatureOverlay` that holds all the new features drawn by the user.

In the case of (2), the `ol.interaction.Modify` instance specifies that it will work on the features inside the `ol.interaction.Select` instance:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: select.getFeatures()
});
```

...and unless I am mistaken, this creates a hidden `ol.FeatureOverlay` that holds the currently selected feature - which is then edited.

However, I can't see a way to combine all 3 - i.e. a user-friendly way to allow a user to draw, select and modify polygons.

What I'd (ideally) want is the functionality of draw/modify, but the moment I hit and keep Ctrl pressed, the cursor is no longer working in "draw" mode, but in "select" mode, allowing me to select one of the existing polygons, and subsequently hiting Delete on the keyboard to delete it, or just edit its vertices with the mouse. As soon as I click outside all polygons, I return to draw/modify mode.

I did the naive test - that of adding an `ol.interaction.Select` to the interactions of the draw/modify Map instance - which lead to hilarious results :-) For example, upon finishing the drawing of a polygon (i.e. when I double-click to close it) it's also getting selected... and clicking anywhere (inside or outside polygons) just starts another new polygon edge, it never selects a pre-existing one - etc.

My only thought of a solution so far is... for me to implement a "VI emulation" :-)  i.e. a "command" mode (that is, the select/modify state) and an "insert" mode (i.e. the draw/modify state) - and you chose what mode you are in from a "state toggle" button inside the map (custom OL3 control) or outside the map (normal HTML button) .

I am, however, looking for a better way, like the one I suggested with holding Ctrl...

Any ideas/suggestions most welcome.

Comment: Does this help? http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html?q=modify You have to use modifier keys, but I managed to draw, delete and modify polygons (after reading the source, it has to be said :-))

Comment: @JohnBarça: Thanks John, but you are just repeating the same reference I had in my own question (modify.js), without telling me how you managed all 3 (draw, select, modify) :-) Care to share your solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that link in your question and I don't have a solution. What is it about that example that does not work for you?

Comment: @JohnBarça: Let me put it very simply - when you click with the mouse, you will either have a selectInteraction on (which selects or deselects visible features) OR a drawInteraction (which creates new polygons). If I add both a draw- and a selectInteraction, as I said in the original question, the results are completely broken. I'd very much like an 'all-3' mode (draw/modify/select) but I don't see how I can do it. In the time since I asked, I have implemented a 'state-toggle' custom control (a button inside the map) that toggles draw/select mode - but it'd be better if all 3 modes were on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never found a solution combining all three modes. Since no answer came up, I might as well share that in the end, having a "modal" form of working (*i.e. hitting a custom control - a map-internal button - to enter "Select Mode"*) is not that bad. I ended up with a "Select mode", a "Draw/Modify mode", and a "Measure" mode - selectable via map-internal buttons:

[image]

In the end, it turned out fine - in hindsight, having a "combo" mode would in fact present significant usability disadvantages.